# Math formula changes in tikz environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, beamer, math-operators

I am trying to write a formula in a `tikzpicture` but it gets changed. The indices for the cumulative product is moved from under the `\prod` to after. See MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [font=\bf\tiny] {$1 - \widehat{S}(t) = \prod_{j:t_j \leq t} \frac{d_{kj}}{n_{j}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{equation}
1 - \widehat{S}(t) = \prod_{j:t_j \leq t} \frac{d_{kj}}{n_{j}}
\end{equation}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Any idea why? Any way around?

Comment: The formula in the `tikzpicture` environment is typeset in text style; so `\prod\limits_{...}` is the answer. Or `$\displaystyle<formula>$` if you want a "big" product symbol.

Comment: Tx, I didn't realize the typeset mode.

Answer (score 6):

Has nothing to do with tikZ. You are using the inline mode with `$...$` which is typeset in that way. Use

```
$ ... \prod\limits_{j:t_j \leq t} ... $
```

Comment: Tx, it works fine.

Comment: @BiauDavid: You should mark this question as answered by clicking the tick mark next to Herbert's answered. That will show others that the problem has been solved, and will give Herbert and you some reputation.